# Jpa + Spring Boot Entity filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, entity

I have a JPA entity thats has a "published" fleg.
For example let's describe it as TestEntity:

- Long testId
- String testDescription
- Boolean published

What I want is every time I access the entity, even when it is another entity's related entity, it is accessed with publish=True. The problem is that i can not use something like `@Filter(condition="published = true")` because there are some cases in witch i do want to access the same entity without that filter, explicititing it in some way.
Is there any simple way to do that?

UPDATE:
I can not set it in the Repository because i need the condition to be setted also in a JOIN from another entity, that does not uses the TestEntity repository.

Answer (score 0):

you can declare a method in your JPARepository as follows :

```
 True    findByActiveTrue()  … where x.active = true
 False   findByActiveFalse() … where x.active = false
```

Possible use of keywords in query methods :

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a good method for me, i need it to work also in a JOIN from another entity.